# How can we get tracking information for Sendable Data extensions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, custom-reports, tracking-extract, sql

I have a Data extension containing Student Data - **Student first name, last name, course, faculty,etc.** I have executed Email Sends on this Data extension.

 
I would now like to get tracking data - for instance - **No. of sends/opens/bounces per student/faculty/course**. 

Would we need to use Custom SQL queries to join data from this Data extension and the various data views? 
I tried hunting the old and new Report Interfaces, however such Tracking Reports are only available for Lists and not DE's.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

For counts of the number of things consider:

1. SQL group by to get counts, SQL would use sendable DE and [data views](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity).
2. Use result from above to update reporting/tracking DE as required.

Comment: hey @mattcameron. thanks! i figured this may be required. :)
what do you exactly mean by 'update reporting/tracking DE'?

Comment: Hello @KanavKhurana query activities can have targets - for overview of how this works refer to [query_activity](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)